# Attach vertices of a mesh to another mesh's vertices

Tags: modeling, vertices, cloth-simulation

I'm currently trying to put a cap at the end of a shirt sleeve to hide the inside (imagine the blue cube is the sleeve and the purple face is the cap):

[image: Sleeve representation]

The sleeve is cloth simulated and there seems to be no way to include the cap in the simulation without it participating in collisions (I don't want the cap to collide with objects). As such, I have to separate the cap from the sleeve. This presents a new problem because now the cap won't stay attached to the sleeve. I want to attach the vertices of the cap to those of the sleeve's so it moves along with the sleeve when it deforms, like this:

[image: Deformation]

Is there a way to attach the vertices of one mesh to another mesh's vertices?

Comment: Try Mesh deform modifier, but it has sort of interpolated binding. For strict movement use parented to cotrol object's geometry Hooks.

Comment: @SergeL Could you perhaps show me how to use the controlling object's geometry in hooks in an answer? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I ditched *Hooks* and used *Armature* approach due to easier maintenance. Result:

[image]

General idea, lower cube is parent, upper - child:

[image]

To do so, add *Armature* object and create bone in edit mode right at the desired point of a control/parent object.

Add new vertex group and name it after corresponding bone.

Add *Child Of* constraint to the bone and select parent object as target and vertex group for geometry control. Click *Set Inverse* to eliminate excessive offset.

For a child object (upper cube) also add vertex group with the same name but another vertex. Both objects in edit mode:

[image]

Final step - add *Armature* modifier to the child object and choose armature object.

[image]